# Performance problems with ItemizedOverlay.draw()

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I have a class:

```
public class WaypointOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
```

It overrides the `draw()` method of the `ItemizedOverlay`.
In my Activity, I have a map with many overlay items as well as a list.  I noticed from traceviewer output and logcat that `MapView.onDraw()` was being called many times even when the map goes untouched. This resulted in a really unresponsive list and map (when I have my `WaypointOverlay` class simply return from these `onDraw` calls, everything performs well)

How can I have the `onDraw` calls happen less frequently - ideally only when the `MapView` changes span?  I tried, in `onDraw`, checking if the `MapView` has the same lat/lon span as it did in the last `onDraw` call, and only drawing if the two are different.  This caused the `OverlayItems` to only appear when the map was panning or zooming.

Any ideas on improving performance?

Comment: Sounds like there are allot of "invalidate()" invocations going on.  Is your code making that call?

Comment: I make no calls to MapView.invalidate().

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have solved this problem (for my case, at least).  In my app, the user can navigate away from the map and then return to it, all in the same activity.  Every time the user returned to the map, I re-added all the overlays I had created.  This meant that way too many overlays were on the map - I couldn't see them because they overlapped.  Calling MapView.getOverlays().clear() has made the map and list perform substantially better.